# How to pay a user with stripe?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am building an ecommerce store like amazon where sellers can sell and they receive money when a product is bought.

I am using stripe api with nodeJS for handeling payments. What is exactly the process of paying a user with stripe?

On their documentation they said of creating an account then transferring fund but in the process what about taking user's payment details like their bank account.

What are the steps which I need to follow for a paying a user out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect). Each merchant you pay will need to be a connected account to your platform.

Comment: So, I need to create a account for every seller using stripe connect. And then I need to add funds to my account and then transfer funds to the account of seller?

Comment: Correct. You should review [Connect use cases](https://stripe.com/en-br/connect/use-cases) so that you can pick the flow that fits your business model the best. I'd suggest speaking with Stripe support directly as they can guide you on designing your integration.